# Angular 6 route transition depending on the route state (stackblitz)

Tags: angular, animation, routes, transition

I would like to perform a route transition depending on the route I'm going to :

For example, if my current route is **home** and I'm going to  **about**, I would like to set .myClass color to green.

But if my current route is **home** and I'm going to **projects**, I would like to set .myClass color to red.

I tried something like this but this doesnt work :

```
transition('about => home', [ /* doesnt work, must use :enter */
    query('.block', style({ opacity: 0 })),
    query('.block', stagger(300, [
      style({ transform: 'translateY(100px)' }),
      animate('1s cubic-bezier(.75,-0.48,.26,1.52)', style({transform: 'translateY(0px)', opacity: 1})),
    ])),
  ]),
```

Here is my Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-motion-v6-final-wbhot5?file=app%2Fhome.component.ts

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see projects in your Stackblitz. I also didn't see ".myClass". So, this is a simple example (use this in your router.animation.ts file) to see the background go from red to green. Maybe it will help you build what you need.

```
import { sequence, trigger, state, stagger, animate, style, group, query as q, 
transition, keyframes, animateChild } from '@angular/animations';
const query = (s, a, o = { optional: true }) => q(s, a, o);

export const routerTransition = trigger('routerTransition', [
  state('about', style({ opacity: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' })),
  transition('home=>about', [ // void <=> *
    animate('1.0s ease-in-out')
  ]),
  state('home', style({ opacity: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' })),
  transition('about=>home', [ // void <=> *
    animate('1.0s ease-in-out')
  ])
]);
```